# How to do a nested loop type operation in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, subset

I need to find a subset of a subset, and I need to do it iteratively, then at each instance of this sub-subset calculate a value and then saving it in a new outputs table.

To explain better I have a data frame similar to the one shown in the pic below;

I need to iterate through the dataset and sum the costs for all person 1 (of Group 1) for Team A (of Group 2).

Then move to person 1 in Team B and do the same, and so on until Person 1 is done.

Then move to Person 2 and do the same for all the teams again.

EXAMPLE BELOW:

[image: Example]

My understanding was to use a nested loop something like:

```
for Person in Group1:

 for Team in Group 2:

  Newcost=sum(cost)

output.append(Person, Team, Newcost)
```

However, I am new to Python and pandas in particular and I am finding it difficult to use the same method I would usually due to having a data frame setting and a different syntax.

I have read about using .groupby and .loc to make my data frame smaller and group by my conditions, but I would need to do it iteratively and with two conditions at the same time, and then finally calculate my value and I am not sure how that would work.

Any suggestion would be much-appreciated Thanks!

Comment: You don't need any nested loops. Pandas provides plenty of tools to do this in a simpler manner. Try something like `df.groupby(by=['Group1', 'Group2'], axis=0).sum()` where `df` is the name of your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it will be easy for you to create a new dataframe instead of operating on the same dataframe. You can use dataframe.loc with the query inside to get the value of Person 1 and Person 2 with respect to the group you want. The way to use .loc can be introduced in [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Comment: I forgot to mention, but I have a large amount of data (say, 100 persons, with many groups as well) that is why I thought it would be impractical to create many separate data frames just to calculate a value for each one.

Comment: you can create and stack data_frame if you want to